# My Files Are On Ubuntu 16.04 that doesn't boot

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot

Long time reader. First time poster.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 setup as my primary boot disk (yes on a separate SSD) next to my Windows 10 installation disk. I tried to update Ubuntu 16.04 but now it boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left corner.

I can boot Ubuntu to the advanced options from the Grub menu, but I can't get Ubuntu to boot/load.

I've tried Ext2Fsd to just grab my files and reload the new Ubuntu from scratch with no luck. I've tried ext2explore to grab my files but no luck there either. It seems that only works for partitions and my OSs are on different drives. I've tried the recovery software that's suggested on the main ubuntu website with no love.

How do I get my files from the borked Ubuntu 16.04... ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use you live session to boot from, mount your disk and copy the files over to an USB or an online storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`